# Grammar with gerund

Tags: gerunds

I always have a coffee before leaving for work.
I always have a coffee before I leave for work.

Are both correct?
Does before take the gerund?

Comment: Yes, both are correct.

Comment: @KateBunting "a coffee"?

Comment: @Man_From_India - Have you never heard a cup of coffee called 'a coffee'?

Comment: @KayeBunting sorry Kate, this is new for me. Thanks.